# when to declare an member of class

Tags: c++

According to Bjarne Stroustrup:

> if (and only if) you use an initialized member in away that requires it to be stored as an oject in memory ,the member must be(uniquely) defined somewhere. The initializer may not be repeated.

(*The C++ Programming Language, 3rd Edition*, Section 10.4.6.1)

He gives this example:

```
class curious{  
     public:  
     static const int c1=7;  
     //..
};  
const int curious::c1;  //necessary
```

Then why it is necessary to define a `static` member, because we may not be initializing it at all?

Also, `const` and reference members are not declared anywhere, even though it is necessary to initialize them (no default constructor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use `c1` in a way that requires it to be stored in memory (such as taking the address, etc) the compiler can replace all uses of `c1` with the value `7`. However, if you use it in such a way that it needs to be stored somewhere, then you have to provide a definition so that it exists in some compilation unit.

Member variables are not declared anywhere because they exist inside the object when it is created; each member variable lives inside the object that is created. `static` variables exist apart from any object instance (that is, the static variable exists regardless of whether the class is instantiated or not) so they need somewhere to live (sometimes) which is independent of a specific instance.